# How to restrict instantiation of inner class only inside outer in Kotlin?

Tags: java, kotlin

Having inner & outer classes I want to restrict instantiation of inner only by the scope of outer class. How can I achieve this in Kotlin ? Java provides it in a very easy way. But is seems that in Kotlin I can't access private field even from inner class.

What Kotlin has:

```
class Outer {
    val insideCreatedInner: Inner = Inner()
    inner class Inner
}

val insideCreatedInner = Outer().insideCreatedInner // Should be visible and accessible
val outsideCreatedInner = Outer().Inner() // I want to disallow this
```

How Java solve this:

```
class Outer {
    Inner insideCreatedInner = new Inner();
    class Inner {
        private Inner() {}
    }
}

Outer.Inner insideCreatedInner = new Outer().insideCreatedInner;
Outer.Inner outsideCreatedInner = new Outer().new Inner(); // 'Inner()' has private access in 'Outer.Inner'
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

*Edited:* To make the `val` field visible and at the same time hide the `Inner` constructor, it may be useful to use an interface that's visible and make the implementation private:

```
class Outer {
    val insideInner: Inner = InnerImpl()

    interface Inner {
        // ...
    }
    private inner class InnerImpl : Inner {
        // ...
    }
}


val outer = Outer()
val outsideInner = outer.InnerImpl() // Error! Cannot access '<init>': it is private in 'Inner'
```

Comment: good option, but not exactly what I need. I've edited sample code in question. I obly need to restrict creation of inner class, but not its visibility.

Comment: One way to fix that would be to define an interface that `Inner` implements that is visible. Another thing is using a `protected constructor`, but then whichever visibility you assign to the Inner constructor would restrict the Outer access the same as from outside of Outer so doesn't work out.

Comment: Kotlin style conventions discourage boilerplate code :) but option with interface seems to be the most suitable for now. Thank you!